# How to tell if it is a counting problem, permutation or combination?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I know all the binomial formulas, I do know how to apply them in all those "high school" problems and the like, but I can tell that my knowledge is shallow and superficial, because after giving some serious thought I still can't tell, in a real life situation if the problem I'm facing is a counting problem, permutation or combination.

For example ( I got this from Khan Acad.):

"Tiffany wants to give her friend a potted plant. At the local florist, the flowers come in 5 colors, and there are 3 types of flower pots."

I can see that it is a counting problem... I can even draw on paper a sketch solution and check that inded, the answer is just 3*5. But, my first gut instinct was to apply the binomial formula like crazy, getting weird results..

Why is that that the binomial formula is not suitable for such exercise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The counting methods (FCP, factorials, permutations, and combinations) are used whenever you have a multi-step process with multiple options at each step.

The most basic form is the **Fundamental Counting Principle** (FCP).
If you have *n1* choices for the first step, *n2* choices for the second step, *n3* choices for the third step, etc. then you have

*n* = *n1* * *n2* * *n3* * ...

total arrangements.  The options for each step do not have to be related to each other. For example, the first step could be picking 1 of 5 flower pots and the second step could be picking 1 of 3 types of flowers.

A special form of the FCP is the **factorial**.  Factorials are used when the choices for each step come from the same group (or set of options) *without replacement*, and we want to arrange (order) the *entire group*.  For example, we want to know how many ways we can arrange five different flower pots on a window sill.  The number of arrangements would be 5! = 5*4*3*2*1 = 120.

**Permutations** are a more versatile variation of the factorial principle.  It is used when (a) the choices for each step come from the same group, (b) without replacement, and (c) the order matters.  The flexibility comes in that we don't have to arrange *all* of the items in the group.  For example, we want to know how many ways we can arrange 3 of the 5 flower pots on the window sill.  The answer would be *P*(5,3) = 60.

Finally, **Combinations** allows us to consider the selections *without regard to the order*.  Combinations are used when (a) the choices for each step come from the same group, (b) without replacement, but (c) the order does *not* matter.  For example, we want to know how many ways we can choose 3 of the 5 flower pots to give as a gift.  Once the pots are chosen and gift wrapped, the recipient won't know (or care) which was selected first, which was selected second, etc.  So we don't care about the order in which they were chosen, only which 3 pots were picked.  The answer would be *C*(5,3) = 10.

I hope that helps clarify when to use which counting method!

Answer (score 2):

You're doing the right thing in trying to understand what the various formulas mean.  Because as you've seen, without that understanding you're just plugging formulas into problems and hoping for the right answer.

A Binomial problem is typically something like "you want to choose 5 people from a group of 20".  Your flower problem could use the Binomial formula, but only in a trivial way.  You want to choose 1 pot out of 5.  The answer is 5, which you know without using the Binomial formula.  Also you want to choose 1 flower out of 3.  So you really did use the Binomial formula, but in this case it was so trivial you didn't even notice.

In fact the Binomial coefficient, 
$\left( \begin{array}{l}
n\\
m
\end{array} \right)$, is often stated in words as 
"n choose m".

A permutation problem is typically something like "you want to know how may ways those 5 people can stand in a line".

Comment: please tell me more about the "group" of problems that this plant problem relates too.. what could other possibilities be?